# Java plugin not working with FireFox 24.3.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.10

Tags: permissions, rhel, java, firefox, plugin

In the about:plugin tab, there is not Java plugin. I have created the symbolic link as suggested. The output of the 'ls -al' command is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 shehab shehab   58 Jun  4 11:21 libnpjp2.so ->
/export/tools/oracle/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

The permission of the libnpjp2.so file is `-rwxr-xr-x`

When I run the Java verifier at www.java.com I am getting the following error.

> We are unable to verify if Java is currently installed and enabled in
>   your browser.
>
> If you have installed Java and there is an error with the
>   verification, there could be a configuration issue (eg. browser, Java
>   control panel, security settings). Try restarting your browser before
>   trying to verify the installation again.

The Java console is not also available in the FF Tools menu. In the `~/.mozilla/firefox/lcus6cpf.default/pluginreg.dat` file I see the following:

```
[INVALID]
/import/projects/FPGA_tools/tools/linux/sun/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/amd6/libnpjp2.so:$
1399495476000:$
```

Any clues what is going on? My Linux admin can run FireFox with Java with his account.